# cannot create two CustomFailure redirect behaviors for devise, one for user another for admin_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am using active_admin in my rails app. Previously, I used to render a custom page on devise login failed. The problem now is that the same custom page gets rendered if active_admin login fails too.

I am stuck with this problem and too far along my development to give up active_admin. Please help.

My CustomFailure definition is here :

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url 
    signin_path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth? 
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

Could someone tell me how to modify the code to have redirect paths for user signin failed and admin_user signin failed. My admin user signin path is : `admin_user_session_path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use scope to solve this :-

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp 
  def redirect_url 
    if warden_options[:scope] == :user 
      signin_path 
    else 
      new_admin_user_session_path 
    end 
  end 
  def respond 
    if http_auth? 
      http_auth 
    else 
      redirect 
    end 
  end 
end
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

application_controller.rb

```
...
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if admin_user
   redirect_to whatever_path
  else
   root_path
  end
end
...
```

I may not know the correct call for the admin user but this should work.

Comment: unfortunately this solution didn't work for me . i don't have the after_sign_in_path_for method since i am not signed in yet --> i am at the login page.